# Applet not working in Chrome,Firefox but working in IE

Tags: applet

I know the subject is similar to some other questions available but none have given satisfactory solution.So here goes the question.I have an applet that works perfectly in IE but doesnt work in Chrome or Firefox.
The trace found in Java console is this:
Java Plug-in 10.25.2.17
Using JRE version 1.7.0_25-b17 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "www.w3.org:80" "connect,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkConnectHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.nwoods.jgo.svg.DefaultDocument.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.nwoods.jgo.svg.DefaultDocument.SVGReadDoc(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.dsp.oam.console.metadatabrowser.datalineage.LineageGraphApplet.start(LineageGraphApplet.java:53)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.start(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.nwoods.jgo.svg.DefaultElement.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at com.nwoods.jgo.svg.DefaultDocument.buildJGoDoc(Unknown Source)
    at com.nwoods.jgo.svg.DefaultDocument.SVGReadDoc(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.dsp.oam.console.metadatabrowser.datalineage.LineageGraphApplet.start(LineageGraphApplet.java:53)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.start(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The applet tag in the page is like this:

```
<applet width="100%" code="/LineageGraphApplet.class"archive="/DataLineageApplet.jar" style="border:0px"   id="lineageapplet" MAYSCRIPT>
<param name="viewDocumentUrl" value="/generateDocument.do?mode=0"/>
</applet>
```

What could be the issue and how to resolve it?Similar questions have seen answers like open the port or seeing the applet work using applet viewer in conjugation with a security policy file granting all permissions or signing the jar.But I still was not able to make it work on Firefox?

Comment: Since you explicitly specified the java version - did it work before? Do you sign your Jar with an official certificate? (If not you need to lower the security settings in your java settings) What Server in which version are you using?

Comment: The jdk is not an issue as the problem is seen with all the java versions.
Signing jar doesnt work.
Server is Oracle Weblogic server-12c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue once - my applet was also running in IE but not in other browsers. However from the amount of information you have given it is difficult to tell. Do you use authentification (like FormLogin, BasicLogin etc) before one can access the applet? If so you can try the following:

Set (thus disable) the [cookie-http-only](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#i1071981) to false.

Comment: Worked like a charm Lonzak